# Convert a specific word within a string to uppercase

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010 and need a macro that changes a specific word in a string to Uppercase. e.g. in "All current sewer pipe is owned by hrsd and not the city." `hrsd` needs to be uppercase `HRSD`.

The following macro works great for single words, but not for a string:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:H3000")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = UCase(Target)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it always the same word?

Answer (score 0):

You could use VBA's Replace function to switch out part of a string as an uppercase value.  For example:

`Dim text As String`

`text = "All current sewer pipe is owned by hrsd and not the city."`

`text = Replace(text, "hrsd", UCase("hrsd"))`

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the `Range.Replace` method.

```
Range("H2:H3000").Replace What:="hrsd", Replacement:="HRSD", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-macro solution is to use the Auto Correct to change hrsd to HRSD. This would fix the problem every time the abbreviation comes up.

1. Navigate to Options>Proofing>Auto Correct Options
2. Under "Replace" type hrsd and under "With" type HRSD, then click
   Add

Note: auto-correct is computer specific so it will fix the workbook on your computer. But if someone wanted to do the same operation on their computer they would need to change their settings.